# "COPY requires at least two arguments, but only one was provided"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Start: `docker build . -f Dockerfile.txt`

Error:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: dockerfile parse error line 8: COPY requires at least two arguments, but only one was provided. Destination could not be determined.
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3-alpine

ENV user user
ENV password pass
ENV email admin@admin.ru

WORKDIR /code

RUN mkdir db
COPY ./requirements.txt /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /code

EXPOSE 8000
VOLUME ["/code/db"]
CMD sh init.sh && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What's unclear from the error? `COPY ./code` has only one argument, but at least two are needed. _"Destination could not be determined"_: copy _to where_?!

Comment: It has two, '.' and '/code', or it's incorrect?

Comment: `./code` is **one** argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type `Copy /?`, these are the first lines:

```
copy /?
Copies one or more files to another location.
```

In other words, you can use this command for copying files, not directories. I would advise you to start using `xcopy` or `robocopy` when you want to copy entire directories.

Heu, I did read your command correctly, I hope?

```
Copy . /code
```

=> you mean that you want to copy the entire current directory to the subdirectory, named "code", don't you?

Comment: Yes. I found solution. For my mistake i had two similar directory with different docker files. i go with latest and it works.

Comment: They're talking about the Dockerfile instruction [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy), which absolutely _does_ copy directories. This answer has nothing to do with it.